# WSO2 ESB XML-centric?

Tags: xml, rest, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

WSO2 ESB seems to be very XML-centric in terms of its components.  Does this mean that all non-XML data needs to be converted into XML in order to get the full benefit of WSO2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the message need to be processed, it needs to be built at the ESB. for that there are default message builders. but if you need the ESB as a pass through. or maybe process only a part of the message, you don't have to build the entire thing. See [1].

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Message+Relay+Building+Blocks

Answer (score 1):

And also note that WSO2 ESB is primarily a bus transporting binary data. The data need to be interpreted into some message format only when the data is required to be processed. It is true that most existing such interpretation is based on XML. But in latest version, 4.5.1 it has more supported non-XML based formats like JSON and REST API. See the [release notes](http://dist.wso2.org/products/enterprise-service-bus/4.5.1/release-notes.html).

Comment: Thanks.  This is also explained nicely here: http://www.slideshare.net/pizak/high-volume-web-api-management-with-the-wso2-esb

Comment: Do you have more details on the "enhanced" JSON support?  For instance, many of the WSO2 base constructs such as 'switch' seem to expect xpath, which isn't applicable to JSON.  Is the expectation that we transform JSON payloads to XML first?

Comment: If you configure the ESB to have JSONBuilder(this is the default builder in ESB 4.5.*) as the message builder for application/json (or similar) content type, the JSON payload will be converted into XML. Then you can query any XPath expression against that XML.